# Generar datos aletorios de color con Python

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar una cierta cantidad de datos para que se me impriman de un color en especial? Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código va así por ahora.

```
def salacine():
    print("_" * 35)
    print("PANTALLA".center(25))
    filas = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
    for num in reversed(range(1, 9)) :
        for letra in filas :
            print(str(num) + letra, end=" ")
        print()
salacine()
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué has intentado o investigado?

Comment: Solo tienes que usar random y anteponer el color a la cadena a imprimir. Acá un [simple ejemplo](https://onlinegdb.com/-mGDiDi3K).

Comment: Para lo del color estoy importando colorama, y eh intentando con un random.choice pero aun no se como enlazarlo con la lista. lo que logro es sacar los numeros por aparte.

Comment: @SweetKriiz edita tu pregunta y pon el código donde usas colorama aunque no funcione.

Comment: ¡No vandalices los títulos de tus preguntas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si usas `colorama`, debes anteponer el color con que quieras mostrar la cadena, en tu caso el color sería `Fore.RED` o `Fore.WHITE`

No está claro qué números son los que quieres colorear de rojo, pero sospecho que se trata de elegirlos al azar. En ese caso podrías simplemente elegir uno cualquiera de esos dos colores usando `random.choice()` y luego aplicar el color elegido delante del número. Así:

```py
import random
from colorama import Fore

def salacine():
    print("_" * 35)
    print("PANTALLA".center(25))
    filas = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
    for num in reversed(range(1, 9)) :
        for letra in filas :
            color = random.choice([Fore.RED, Fore.WHITE])
            print(color+ str(num) + letra, end=" ")
        print()
salacine()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Otra posibilidad

Otra posibilidad, más útil, sería que la función reciba un par de parámetros. El primero sería una lista con todos los nombres de las butacas a mostrar, y el segundo sería otra lista (o mejor un conjunto, para mayor eficiencia) con todos los nombres de las butacas ocupadas. La función recorrería la lista de butacas a imprimir y elegiría el color rojo si esa butaca está en la lista de ocupadas, o el blanco si no lo está.

Una función así podría ser la siguiente:

```py
def salacine(asientos, ocupados):
    print("_" * 26)
    print("PANTALLA".center(26))
    for asiento in asientos:
      color = Fore.RED if asiento in ocupados else Fore.WHITE
      print(color + asiento, end=" ")
      if asiento.endswith("I"):   # Pasar a la siguiente fila
        print()
```

Ahora, habría que generar una lista con todos los nombres de butacas. Una forma muy compacta de lograrlo es utilizando `itertools.product()` y una expresión generadora:

```
from itertools import product

asientos = list(f"{n}{c}" for n, c in product("87654321","ABCDEFGHI"))
```

Eso genera una lista que contiene `['8A', '8B', '8C', '8D', '8E', '8F', '8G', '8H', '8I', '7A', '7B', '7C', '7D', ...]` etc. que será lo que hay que pasarle a la función como primer parámetro.

Por otro lado hay que generar otra lista (o mejor un conjunto, pues en los conjuntos la búsqueda es más rápida) con las butacas que quieras marcar como ocupadas. Por ejemplo:

```
ocupados = set(['7A' , '5F'])
```

Si quieres hacer pruebas eligiendo al azar 20 butacas ocupadas de la sala, puedes usar `random.sample()` así:

```
ocupados = set(random.sample(asientos, 20))
```

En una ejecución de prueba, han salido los siguientes asientos ocupados:

```
{'1F', '5F', '8B', '6F', '3G', '8I', '4C', '2H', '2F', '8F', '5H', '2D', '6C', '5D', '4B', '3H', '7F', '7D', '2A', '2B'}
```

Ahora, llamando a `salacine(asientos, ocupados)` el resultado es:

[image: Resultado]